# How do I print each element of a list on individual lines, preceded by the line number in python?

Tags: python, list, element, line-numbers

How can I print each individual element of a list on separate lines, with the line number of the element printed before the element? The list information will also be retrieved from a text file.

So far I have,

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rt') as num:
    t = num.readlines()
    print("\n"[:-1].join(t))
```

Which currently gives the read-out:

```
Blah, blah, blah
etc, etc, etc
x, x, x
```

But I want this read-out:

```
1. Blah, blah, blah
2. etc, etc, etc
3. x, x, x
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Why not just `"".join(t)`? -- "\n"[:-1].join(t)` is pretty difficult to read...

Comment: It would be easy for you if you explicitly iterate over the lines, instead of printing them through a join expression.

Comment: I've switched it to "" from "\n" now, the [:-1] is to get rid of the \n that is automatically added to the end of each element in a list.

Comment: @user1825241 -- I think you're confused.  You're joining a bunch of strings (which have a newline at the end) inserting an empty string in between each.  That gives the same result as stripping the newline and joining with a newline, but the latter case is not what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and use [`str.rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove the all types of trailing whitespaces from the string. and you can also use `rstrip('\n')` if you're sure that the newline is going to be `\n` only.:

```
for i,x in enumerate(t,1):
    print ("{0}. {1}".format(i,x.rstrip()))
```

Comment: This will give you an extra newline per line.  (You get one from the line and 1 from `print`.)

Comment: Now you're stripping characters from both ends.  Perhaps `.rstrip('\n')`?

Comment: @mgilson I think then just `rstrip()` is okay, as some OS also use `\r\n` as newline.

Comment: But `rstrip` will take off all trailing whitespace -- It's usually not a problem, but it's worth considering at least.  If you open the file with universal newline support, then you're set with just `.rstrip('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

This seems easiest with `enumerate`, printing each line as you go:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as num:
    for i,line in enumerate(num,1):
        print("%d. %s"%(i,line[:-1]))  #equivalent to `"{0}. {1}".format(i,line[:-1])`
```

Of course, you could wrap the whole thing in a generator if you want to use `join`:

```
def number_lines(fname):
    with open(fname,'r') as f:
       for i,line in enumerate(f,1):
           yield "%d. %s"%(i,line[:-1])

print('\n'.join(number_lines(sys.argv[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`fileinput.input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) it is possible to iterate over file line by line. When `fileinput.input` returns next line, we [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) it to track line number. As input already contains newline we use [`end=""`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) in `print` method so it doesn't append unnecessary newline. Using [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=format#format) to convert line number and content to formated representation.

```
import fileinput

for number, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(['some_file.txt']), 1):
    print('{0}. {1}'.format(number, line), end="")
```